# How to create java model class to read xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, java-8, xmlmapper

I am new to xml parsing and currently I have an xml file that I am trying to read through XmlMapper in a junit test case. But when I run the test, there is no error obtained but a null value for the file.
I have the following Xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root version="1.0">
    </Header>
    <Value line="1">
        <Id> 20868PW </Id>
        <Price> 7 </Price>
     </Item>
</Root>
```

Below is the code for reading the xml file-

```
private MyResponse getMockResponse() throws IOException {
 XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
 File file = new File("src/test/MockedFile.xml");
 return xmlMapper.readValue(file, MyResponse.class);
}
```

MyResponse.java

```
public class MyResponse {
  @XmlElement(name="Root")
  private RootResponse root;
}
```

RootResponse.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")

public class RootResponse {
 @XmlElement(name="Value")
 private List<Value> value;
 @XmlElement(name="Header")
 private List<Header> header;
 @XmlAttribute
 private String version;
```

Is there something missing in my model class because of which the file is not read correctly and returns root = null?

Comment: I think there is an error in your XML file. <Header> is missing.

Comment: Header element is there but it is empty, does the model not accept empty elements?

Comment: Maybe it should be <Header />? W3schools XML page: "Empty XML Elements An element with no content is said to be empty. In XML, you can indicate an empty element like this: <element></element> or you can use an empty tag, like this (this sort of element syntax is called self-closing): <element /> The two forms above produce identical results in an XML parser."

Answer (score 0):

which xml parse library you used ? Not sure that it could slove the first line   which is  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`  , as suggestion , you can try to rm the first line  of xml file , if it work , Obviously , you can change your xmp parse library.

Comment: I have only used XmlMapper and a dependency in pom : jackson-dataformat-xml

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is invalid.

1. This is invalid tag :  `</Header>`
2. Correct way to write empty tag is : `<Header/>`
3. Its a good practice to validate xml on an online parser like https://jsonformatter.org/xml-parser